How to Configure Doxygen to Use Markdown Headings as Root Headings in PDF Output Instead of Filename?
I am using Doxygen, version 1.10.0, to generate a PDF from a markdown file. The PDF is generated successfully, but I am facing an issue where the top-level headings in my markdown file (# Heading 1) are being treated as subheadings in the PDF. The root heading in the generated PDF becomes the markdown file name instead of the first-level heading from the markdown content.
How can I configure Doxygen to treat the first-level headings (# Heading 1) in my markdown file as the root headings in the generated PDF, rather than using the file name as the main heading?
Example:
Filename: overview.md
File content:
Some text before first heading

# Project Overview

This is the introduction to the project.

# Module name

Some info about module

## Features

Here goes features description.

Expected result:
Some text before first heading

1. Project Overview

This is the introduction to the project.

2. Module name

Some info about module

2.1. Features

Here goes features description.

Actual result:
1. overview.md

Some text before first heading

1.1. Project Overview

This is the introduction to the project.

1.2. Module name

Some info about module

1.2.1 Features

Here goes features description.

In case there is no text before first heading, actual results looks like:
1. Project Overview

This is the introduction to the project.

1.1. Module name

Some info about module

1.1.1 Features

Here goes features description.


Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you add a small example to the question? Can you indicate in the question where you would like to have the mentioned header.

@Albert I updated the question with more details

Strange I see in LaTeX and HTML the "Excepted Results". I'm using an empty settings file. So probably there is something in your, unpublished, settings file (publish the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile) or something else in your project that causes the unwanted behavior.

@Albert Sorry, I gave too simple example. In case there is just one heading of level one and it is first thing in the file, result would be as you got, but in case there is some other text before heading, or there are more headings of level one in the document, actual result would be as described in question.

Doxygen needs an page title and normally takes the first header (# line or \page command) but in your case there is some information in front of it and thus doxygen "invents" its own page title. You can add your own page title by placing a # line or \pagecommand  as first line. When you don't want to show this line in none doxygen documentation you have to enclose the line like<!--! ... --->` though this requires doxygen 1.12.0 or later.

My issue is that the page title is being used as the main heading, rather than my own Markdown headings (e.g., 'Project Overview', 'Module Name'). While this behavior makes sense when generating a document from multiple files, it doesn't seem appropriate when generating a document from just one file.
